# How to store/load list of python class with dictionary in JSON

Tags: python, json

Im trying to store/load a dictionary of name: class to/from JSON but its not storing the dictionary variable from the class, just the other ones.

My class has

```
class Test():
    a = ''
    b = 0.0
    c = {}
```

Ive tried using

```
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return o.__dict__
```

to encode it but __dict__ only returns the a and b variables.  Im essentially doing

```
testDict = {}
test = Test()
testDict['a'] = test
test. a = 'asdf'
test.b = 1.4
test.c['qwert'] = 5
with open('test.json', 'w') as outfile:
   output = json.dump(testDict, outfile, indent=3, cls=MyEncoder)
```

and when I try exporting to JSON it just exports everything but the dictionary

```
{
   "a": {
      "a": "asdf",
      "b": 1.4
   }
}
```

What do I need to do to export all of each instance of the class in my dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. From an initial glance, it looks like the issue here is that the initial value of `c` is scoped to the class `Test`, rather than the instance `test` itself.

You can kind of test this out by changing the assignment slightly, to `test.c = {'qwert': 5}`, instead of updating the `dict` object directly. For example:

```py
import json


class Test():
    a = ''
    b = 0.0
    c = {}


class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return o.__dict__

testDict = {}
test = Test()
testDict['a'] = test
test. a = 'asdf'
test.b = 1.4
test.c = {'qwert': 5}

with open('test.json', 'w') as outfile:
   output = json.dump(testDict, outfile, indent=3, cls=MyEncoder)
```

The *long-term solution* would likely be to refactor code to use something like [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) instead:

```py
import json
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, asdict


@dataclass
class Test:
    a: str = ''
    b: float = 0.0
    c: dict = field(default_factory=dict)


class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return asdict(o)


testDict = {}
test = Test(a='asdf', b=1.4)
testDict['a'] = test
test.c['qwert'] = 5

with open('test.json', 'w') as outfile:
    output = json.dump(testDict, outfile, indent=3, cls=MyEncoder)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have encountered is a difference between mutable and immutable objects + a difference between instance attribute and class attribute.

This code:

```py
class Test():
    a = ''
    b = 0.0
    c = {}
```

Creates a class (type) object with class attributes a='', b=0.0 and c={}.

Now when you create an instance:

```py
test = Test()
```

It has **no** instance attributes, ie. `test.__dict__` is empty.

When you assign

```py
test.a = 'asdf'
test.b = 1.4
```

You create an instance attributes test.a and test.b, thus `__dict__` now contain those.

However when you do this:

```py
test.c['qwert'] = 5
```

You are only referencing class attributes, instead of creating a new dictionary.

Therefore what you end up with is:

```py
Test.__dict__ # -> {'a': '', 'b': 0.0, 'c': {'qwerty': 5}} # class object __dict__
test.__dict__ # -> {'a': 'asdf', 'b': 1.4} # instance __dict__
```

Afterward when you reference `o.__dict__`, 'c' is simply not there.

You can use the constructor to ensure instance attributes are always set:

```py
class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        a = ''
        b = 0.0
        self.c = {}
```

or [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), they will create a constructor for you:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, Dict


@dataclass
class Test:
    a: str
    b: float
    c: Dict[str, Any]
```

For my own purposes, I use [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/), to avoid recreating the same pattern every time I create a class. Pydantic also validates the field values during assignment.

```
from typing import Any, Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Test(BaseModel):
    a: str
    b: float
    c: Dict[str, Any]
```